# FMX Форма с прозрачностью не захватывается в OBS

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, obs

Собственно как заставить форму с включенной прозрачностью захватываться в **OBS**?

Без прозрачности
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
С ней
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**P.S**.Если кто не знает что такое **OBS**, то это программа для стриминга.

Answer (score 0):

Пробуй в настройках захвата экрана поставить не "Авто", а (к примеру) Игровой режим. Разреши там прозрачность (+ захват дополнительных оверлеев).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А тут вообще никакие окна не захватывает.

Comment: @伝説の Allow transparency разве не оно?

Comment: @NMD А толку, никакие окна не захватывает, только игры.